# How to include backslashes in Ruby/Rails activerecord sql conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm attempting to search for all entries that match a particular regex.

```
match_rules = "(^|\W)#{word}(\W|$)"
@dogs += Dog.where(["owner REGEXP :term", {:term => match_rules}])
```

This is hopefully pretty straightforward, but the resulting behaviour is a bit weird. The sql generated looks like this:

```
SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|W)doe(W|$)')
```

when what I want it to look like is

```
SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|\W)doe(\W|$)')
```

The problem is that it's dropping my backslash symbols - a pretty crucial part of the queries functionality! The obvious thing wrong here is that backslashes in Ruby double-quoted strings need to be escaped, so we can write it as

```
match_rules = "(^|\\W)#{word}(\\W|$)"
```

and get it to persist in our string... but when I triy to insert it, I get:

```
SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|\\W)doe(\\W|$)')
```

Which means that it's "escaping" those backslashes before it inserts them. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Rails isn't doing anything to your backslashes, Ruby is. Backslashes have a meaning in string literals, especially in double quoted string literals.

Comment: Ah, yeah, of course. I was getting thrown by the fact that doing it with escaped slashes like I originally did was leading to double-slashes in the result. >_< Obviously what was happening was that it was removing them (seeing them as escape characters) when there was one, and putting them into the string correctly when there was two... but then inserting an additional escape character at some point. I presume that the additional escape character IS in fact coming from Rails, so Rails is definitely doing *something* to my backslashes - just not what I thought it was.

Answer (score 3):

You can use single quotes to avoid unescaping of your literal:

```
match_rules = '(^|\W)#{word}(\W|$)'
```

Also, how did you check the resulting SQL? Ruby can show it to you either escaped, or un-escaped, depending on the API you use:

```
sql = "SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|\\W)doe(\\W|$)')"
puts sql
# SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|\W)doe(\W|$)')
p sql
# "SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|\\W)doe(\\W|$)')"
```

Comment: Huh, wow. I wasn't even aware of the difference between "p" and "puts" in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape them. replace the first line with:

```
match_rules = "(^|\\W)#{word}(\\W|$)"
```

Comment: This gives me: SELECT `dogs`.* FROM `dogs`  WHERE (name REGEXP '(^|\\W)doe(\\W|$)') which is still wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question thanks to an improved understanding of the actual problem due to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some example how use regexp with sql in `postgresql` regexp operator `~` but this should work in `mysql` with `regexp` operator:

```
=> reg = %r/^\d+/
=> /^\d+/
=> reg.source
=> "^\\d+"    # Note that escape sequences are retained as is.
=> User.where('email ~ :term', {term: reg.source}).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (email ~ '^\\d+')"
```

Some help [`Regexp::source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Regexp.html#method-i-source) and `%r{...}` literal for `Regexp::new` constructor.